# Magento Customer Wizard Registration

Tags: magento, registration

I'm trying to create a simple registration for the magento visitors using custom steps. I need to create a wizard that helps the users to follow a path previously set in the administration panel.

At the moment I have created the extension but I am having some difficulties to create the front-end wizard form. What I'd like to achieve is a multi registration form where if the user go from the first form to the second one Magento has to save the data and wait if the user wants to go on the next new form and so on...

Here a mockup: http://minus.com/lF3krBVJG0WEM

**How have I to create a multiform that follow this behaviour?**

Regards